# How to make tfl widget bigger on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

so I am trying to use the TFL widget on my jQuery Mobile site, however it is tiny.
I tried setting the height and the width through CSS but it doesn't work, I want it to cover the full page. I've also tried using both versions on the TFL website, the fixed width one and the variable width one but none of them have worked properly.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Sorry the formatting sort of messed up.
Here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">        </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
 <body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="tflwidget">
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/widgets/serviceboard/embeddable/serviceboard-iframe-stretchy.js"></script></div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; left:0; right:0">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>




</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you won't do much to an iframe with css.
You want to explicitly set the height and width attributes of the iframe, 100% might be the right value if the parent element is big enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but how do I do that lol since I only have the link to the original javascript and I cannot change that.